# Check if one person is 100 days older than the other in C

Tags: arrays, c, loops

My task is to check if one student in the group is 100 days older than the other one. The maximum number of students is 1000. When calculating, leap years and other characteristics such as the number of days in month should be taken in account. I don't know why my code doesn't work.If I enter the wrong date(32/33/2000), I have an infinite loop with 'Wrong input'.If the date is correct,the code doesn't print anything even if the difference is 100 days. I am beginner, and I hope you could help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int days[13]={0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    int daysleap[13]={0,31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

    int s, month, year, day, i, j = 0, totaldays, a[1000];
    do {
        printf("Number of students: ");
        scanf("%d", & s);
        if (s < 1 || s > 100)
            printf("Incorrect input");
    } while (s < 1 || s > 1000);

    for (i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        scanf("%d,%d,%d", & day, & month, & year);
        if (year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)) {
            if (day < 1 || day > daysleap[month]) {
                printf("Incorrect input");
                i = i - 1;
                continue;
            } else if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
                printf("Incorrect input");
                i = i - 1;
                continue;
            } else {
                for (i = 1; i < year; i++) {
                    totaldays = 0;
                    totaldays += 366;
                }
                for (i = 1; i < month; i++)
                    totaldays += daysleap[i];
                totaldays += day;
                a[j] = totaldays;
                j++;
            }

        } else {
            if (day < 1 || day > days[month]) {
                printf("Incorrect input");
                i = i - 1;
                continue;
            } else if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
                printf("Incorrect input");
                i = i - 1;
                continue;
            } else {
                for (i = 1; i < year; i++) {
                    totaldays = 0;
                    totaldays += 365;
                }
                for (i = 1; i < month; i++)
                    totaldays += days[i];
                totaldays += day;
                a[j] = totaldays;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        for (j = i; j < s; j++) {
            while (i < s && j < s) {
                if (i != j && (a[j] - a[i] == 100))
                    printf("Student %d is 100 days older from Student %d", j + 1, i + 1);
                if (i != j && (a[j] - a[i] == -100))
                    printf("Student %d is 100 days older from Student %d", i + 1, j + 1);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly before posting. This is barely readable. And provide a failing test case where you state the actual and expected behavior.

Comment: I hope this is okay. @klutt

Comment: @Michael Better, but far from good. Fixed it for you.

Comment: But you should really learn to debug. This might help: https://github.com/klutt/debug-small-c-programs

Answer (score 0):

This

```
for (i = 1; i < year; i++) {
    totaldays = 0;
    totaldays += 366;
}
```

Is equivalent to this

```
totaldays = 366;
```

You probably wanted to do this

```
totaldays = 0;
for (i = 1; i < year; i++) {
    totaldays += 366;
}
```

However the logic is incorrect. Let's say that the year is 2000. It is a leap year, but 1999 is not. You should add 366 for leap years and 365 fon non-leap years.

I don't know if fixing it is enough for the program to work. Anyway I was eager to code and I made a program that relies on the difference between the dates as they are rather than on the difference between the dates as distance from the 1st January of the year 0. Check this approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 50

int main() {

    int m[12] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    int p[N][3]; // person: day, month, year
    int n; // number of people
    // if the date is in a leap year, then one of the two subscripts gets a value of 1
    // if the date is before the 29th February leap[][0] = 1, otherwise leap[][1] = 1
    int leap[N][2] = {};
    int tot[N]; // sum of days in the birth year
    int dif; // difference in days between two dates

    puts("How many people?");
    do {
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }
    while( (n < 2 || n > N) && puts("Try again...") );
    
    puts("Enter their birth days please.");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        
        if( scanf("%d%*c%d%*c%d", &p[i][0], &p[i][1], &p[i][2]) == 3 && p[i][0] > 0 && p[i][1] > 0 && p[i][1] < 13 ) {
            
            if( (!(p[i][2]%4) && p[i][2]%100) || !(p[i][2]%400) ) {
            
                if( p[i][1] == 0 || (p[i][1] == 2 && p[i][0] < 29) ) leap[i][0] = 1;
                else leap[i][1] = 1;
            }
            
            if( ( leap[i][1] && ((p[i][1] == 1 && p[i][0] > 29) || (p[i][1] != 1 && p[i][0] > m[p[i][0]-1])) ) || (!leap[i][1] && p[i][0] > m[p[i][0]-1]) ) {
                
                puts("Wrong input, try again");
                --i;
            }
        }
        else {
            puts("Wrong input, try again");
            --i;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            
        tot[i] = p[i][0];
            
        for(int j = 0; j < p[i][1]-1; j++ ) {
                
            tot[i] += m[j];
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    
        if( p[i][2] - p[i+1][2] < - 1 ) dif = 999;
        else if( p[i][2] - p[i+1][2] > 1 ) dif = -999;
        else {
            dif = tot[i+1] - tot[i];
        
            if( leap[i][0] && leap[i+1][1] ) ++dif;
            else if( leap[i+1][0] && leap[i][1] ) --dif;
        
            if( p[i][2] - p[i+1][2] == - 1 ) dif += 365;
            else if( p[i][2] - p[i+1][2] == 1 ) dif -= 365;
        }
        
        if( dif > 100) printf("Student #%d is 100 days older than student #%d", i+1, i+2);
        else if( dif < 100) printf("Student #%d is 100 days older than student #%d", i+2, i+1);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Yes it would be more readable using `day[]`, `month[]` and `year[]` istead of `p[][0]`, `p[][1]` and `p[][2]`.

It would be even better to use an array of structures, like `Date dates[N]` with the type `Date` defined as follows

```
typedef struct {
    int day, month, year;
    int leapPre = 0, leapPost = 0;
    int tot;
} Date;
```

With `leapPre` and `leapPost` being what `leap[][0]` and `leap[][1]` were.

Comment: But, the problem is that diff shoud be equal to 100 not >= or <=. When I put == it works for the dates that don't include february for example 23 8 2000 1 12 2000, but not for 1 12 2000 and 10 4 2000

Comment: Yes I had a logic error, test it again now

Comment: Just one question: Is there any way I could restrict the input of day,month and year to be separated by comma?

Comment: And this code reports a mistake if day=29 for a leap year, for example 29 2 2000

Comment: And also doesn't give the correct result; for any date I enter it prints that one is 100 days older than the other

Comment: I tried to fix the 29 2 2000 issue but I just ended up making an if more complex without solving anything. Anyway I suggest you to create a structure and rewrite the program. Jn this way you can understand how it works and make all the fix that you need. Ps: to allow only commas use `%d,%d` instead of `%d%*c%d`